# Create a numpy array with a user-defined method which assign a value

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I need to create an empty numpy array (of unknown shape, at the creation time), and to be  able to use specific methods (named "upload" and "download") in order to update its values and retrieve them.

Some more context: opencv has a class called cuda_GpuMat, which when you want to perform calculations on the GPU, you suppose to first create an instance of one, and then assign the np.array you wish to work on, using the upload() method, for example:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import cv2.cuda as cvc 
   
x = np.arange(3)
x_gpu = cv2.cuda_GpuMat()
x_gpu.upload(x)
x_gpu = cvc.multiply(x_gpu, x_gpu)
x_gpu.download()

output:
array([[0],
       [1],
       [4]], dtype=int32)
```

I want a compatible class for regular cpu, so I can run the same code (only change: import cv2.cuda as cvc to import cv2 as cvc).
I read about [ndarray subclassing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.subclassing.html) but couldn't figure out how to do it properly.

what have I tried?

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

class CpuMat(np.ndarray):

    def __new__(subtype, shape=0, **kwargs):
        obj = super(CpuMat, subtype).__new__(subtype, shape, **kwargs)
        obj.emptyflag = True
        return obj

    def __array_finalize__(self, obj):
        if obj is None: return

    def upload(self, img):
        self.img = img
        self.emptyflag = False

    def download(self):
        return self.img

    def empty(self):
        return self.emptyflag
```

Obviously this wouldn't work because, as in the example above, the cv2 functions operate on the array itself, but in my implementation the array is stored in the "img" attribute of the object.
I've tried several versions of the above (for example, I tried to define a **repr**() function of the class to return self.img, but it have to be a string so it didn't work), but I'm not sure I'm in the right direction to the solution.
So any help here would be great.

Comment: Why are you trying to subclass from `ndarray`???

Comment: because opencv functions input should be 'ndarray'

Comment: You won't be able to get past this line: `x_gpu = cvc.multiply(x_gpu, x_gpu)`. Nothing you can do about that except making a bunch of wrappers for `cv2` that return your custom class.

Comment: How about just free-standing functions that provide a common api, and select the code path depending on the type? e.g. `mat_upload(m, img)` which will invoke the member method on `m` if it's a GpuMat, or just just assign to it if it's an `numpy.ndarray`? Probably less work than wrapping every single opencv function you'll use.

Comment: OpenCV, which is written in C++, will not be impressed by user-defined python classes. all the CUDA stuff in OpenCV **really** needs CUDA to work. there is no way to fake that. if you use regular (non-cuda) OpenCV functions, all the cuda stuff (upload/download) has to be removed, *or* you have to write wrappers for all the regular functions so you can pretend it's a gpumat and you have functions that act on it... when it's not, and they don't. what you're attempting is just unreasonable. no other way to put it.

Comment: @DanMašek, I'm currently using something like what you suggested, but I was wondering if there more elegant way.

Comment: Thank you all for your comment regarding OpenCV. So I understand what I asked is not relevant to implement using OpenCV. 
However, the principal question is still on the table: is it not possible to create such a class as I asked in the first paragraph of my question?

Comment: Well, it depends on how far you're willing to go :) Doesn't seem like a good idea tho, but nevertheless... to have it as transparent as you desire, you'd need a custom modified build of OpenCV Python bindings. That means grokking the code generator to be able to patch it, and then at the minimum adding code to convert your custom objects to `cv::Mat`s. If you also want to have the return values be of your custom class, instead of having to rely on the `dst` argument, you'd also have to change code generation for return values, to make it your calss instead of numpy arrays.

Comment: ...It's probably more sensible to have separate implementations for CPU and CUDA, and have a solid unit test collection that makes sure both behave the way you want. I wouldn't be surprised if there were different ways to optimize the performance of each of them. After all, if there was a simple way to unify them in a transparent way, it would probably exist as part of the unified API (UMat) -- but AFAIK that's only CPU vs OpenCL, but I may be wrong there.